# Log4j2 configuration not able to write to a file

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2, spring5

`Log4j2` configuration not able to write to a file with `Spring 5`. It shows the logs on the console but nothing gets written to the file. However the file is getting generated but it's empty.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**src/main/resources/log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="warn">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="basePath">/apps/istore/logs</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/istore.log" filePattern="${basePath}/istore-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
            <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="istore-logger" level="info" additivity="true">
                <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info"/>
            </Logger>
            <Root level="info" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="console"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

**MyFilter.java**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@doFilterInternal");
        ...
        ...     
}
```

**Console Logs:**

```
[INFO ] 2020-06-09 12:30:49.381 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] MyFilter - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@doFilterInternal
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a LoggerConfig with name "istore-logger". You have created a Logger named MyFilter (you don't show a package statement so I am assuming it doesn't have one. When you log in doFilterInternal you are logging to the MyFilter Logger. Log4j will look for a Logger with that name. There is none. I will then strip off the last token and again look for a matching Logger. The string is now "" so it will match the root logger and log to the console.

In short, you aren't getting anything logged to the file since you don't have any loggers that match the LoggerConfig name that cause it to be used.